# Assign "points" based on column values and sum in new column using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this sample data frame:

```
df_samp = pd.DataFrame({'Athlete': ['Bob', 'John', 'Ross'], 'Distance': [7.4, 6.01, 5], 'Under8': [1, 0, 1.2], 'Under745': [5.1, 0, 3], 'Under730': [0, 0, .8]})
```

We have an individual that ran a certain number of miles, in `Distance`, and then we have columns that denote if any of those miles were run under a certain pace: `Under8` - under 8 min/mile pace, `Under745` - under a 7:45 min/mile pace, etc. If there's a zero in the column, that means no miles were run under a specific pace. And if all the columns have zero, that means the runner ran all of their miles above an 8 minute/mile pace.

Point structure:

If an individual runs one mile `Under8` - they get an extra 0.25 points, and if they run 0.2 miles `Under8`, they would just get 20% of that extra 0.25 points. Or, if they run 1.5 miles in the same column, they would get 0.25 plus another half of 0.25.

If an individual runs one mile `Under745` - they would get an extra 0.5 points, and if they run 0.8 `Under745`, they would just get 80% of that extra 0.5 points. Or, if they run above one mile, say 2.5 miles, they would get 0.5 points per mile, plus the extra half mile, which would be half of 0.5.

I would keep increasing the points incrementally by 0.25 - but that's not needed in the example. Here's what I have:

```
# blank lists to append points
under8 = []
under745 = []

# scoring condition chain
for i in df_samp['Under8']:
    if i in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
        und8 = i + 0.25
        under8.append(und8)
    else: #this would become elif as I pass more conditions
        pass
   #under8.append(und8)
```

I know you create a new `Points` column by assignment, `df_samp['Points'] = ...`, but how do I create and append whatever the calculation is in the if statement?

Comment: Hi @papelr - please simplify your question to a specific programming question. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this summary of what is [on topic at stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Context is key; but thanks. Took out some prose. Aware of the needs for a simple question.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! And it's not really. The question is about simple math operations and workflows with a pandas DataFrame, not about marathons. But good luck with the analysis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df_samp['Points'] = df_samp.apply(lambda x: x['Distance']*1 + x['Under8']*1.25 + x['Under745']*1.5 + x['Under730']*1.75, axis=1)
```

Output

```
    Athlete  Distance  Under8  Under745  Under730  Points
0     Bob      7.40     1.0       5.1       0.0   16.30
1    John      6.01     0.0       0.0       0.0    6.01
2    Ross      5.00     1.2       3.0       0.8   12.40
```

Comment: Holy crap it's that simple?

Comment: Yeah it really is :)

Comment: Why use apply here and not just `df['Points'] = df['Distance']*1 + df['Under8']*1.25 + df['Under745']*1.5 + df['Under730']*1.75`? way faster & more pandariffic

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Just to annoy you

Comment: Will take both ways into account. But it worked. But for those of us English majors - does the multiplication by 1.25, 1.5, etc. take into account those fractions of a mile in the sample df? Just checking

Comment: @papelr it's saying take whatever was there and add an additional 25 percent, or 50 percent, etc.  So yes it carries over the original value plus adds the additional

Comment: This double counts each mile, no?

Comment: I don't think so - I'm giving everyone points just for running, even if they ran slow. May running challenge for college buds, but the Distance col does what I want, I think

Answer (score 1):

Is this acceptable?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_samp = pd.DataFrame({'Athlete': ['Bob', 'John', 'Ross'], 'Distance': [7.4, 6.01, 5], 'Under8': [1, 0, 1.2], 'Under745': [5.1, 0, 3], 'Under730': [0, 0, .8]})
bonus_structure = (np.arange(1, len(df_samp.columns) - 1)) * .25
df_samp['Points'] = df_samp.apply(lambda row : np.dot(row.values[2:], bonus_structure) + row.values[1], axis=1)
print(df_samp)
```

Output:

```
  Athlete  Distance  Under8  Under745  Under730  Points
0     Bob      7.40     1.0       5.1       0.0   10.20
1    John      6.01     0.0       0.0       0.0    6.01
2    Ross      5.00     1.2       3.0       0.8    7.40
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do math with numerical columns as entire arrays. This is significantly faster than looping through the elements or using `df.apply`, as the array operations are written in optimized, compiled C code.

```py
df['Points'] = (
    df['Distance']
    + 0.25 * df['Under8']
    + 0.5 * df['Under745']
    + 0.75 * df['Under730']
)
```

See the pandas docs on [Data Structures: Working with Vectorized Operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html#vectorized-operations-and-label-alignment-with-series) for more info on the topic.